# Compact notation for limit at two different points of interest

Tags: notation, article-writing

Is it acceptable to replace
$$
\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\lim_{x\to b}f(x)=c
$$
with
$$
\lim_{x\to \{a,b\}}f(x)=c?
$$
If not, is there another way I could state such a fact in a compact manner without having to write out the limit twice?

Edit:
Another viable option I considered was
$$
\lim_{x\to a\lor b}f(x)=c.
$$
I am hoping there is some notation for this that won't require any explanation prior to using it in a proof.

Comment: I suggest writing $\lim_{(x-a)(x-b)\to 0} f(x) = c$. If this doesn’t seem right, maybe define $y=(x-a)(x-b)$ and write $\lim_{y\to 0 }f(x) =c$.

Comment: I see no problem with that notation

Comment: After you defined them the first time, just use $c$ going forward. Isn't this more compact if you worry about wasting ink or toner?

Comment: @Meowdog Which one? In my post, edit, or the one suggested by Tavish?

Comment: How about $\lim\limits_{x\to L}f(x)=c$ where $L\in\{a,b\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both variants are not commonly used notations and have drawbacks.

- When looking at
  \begin{align*}
  \lim_{\color{blue}{x\to \{a,b\}}}f(x)=c
  \end{align*}
  we consider the limit of a point $x$ to a set $\{a,b\}$. This is not the intention here and it's not obvious, that  elements of the set should be taken instead.
- The other variant
  \begin{align*}
  \lim_{\color{blue}{x\to a\lor b}}f(x)=c
  \end{align*}
  uses a boolean operator $\lor$, but $a$ and $b$ are not logical expressions.

> I think a useful proposal to reduce the number of limits is stated in the comment section by @JWTanner.
> \begin{align*}
> \lim_{\color{blue}{x\to L}}f(x)=c\qquad\qquad \color{blue}{L\in\{a,b\}}
> \end{align*}
> This is mathematically precisely what we want to say and we also keep common notation.